# Easiest GUI on Linux for a basic HTML output stream

Tags: image, ubuntu, user-interface, stream

I would like to develop a simple crawler which scans auction sites, grab the result page every minute, compute the difference (new items put by auction), extract the HTML code for the new items and send them to a GUI running on Ubuntu.
Everything up to the HTML extraction I can do in several ways (coding it, or using automation frameworks), and that's not a problem.

My problem is for the last part: a stream of small "blocks" (they might be HTML code, or simply images) which runs in a Ubuntu GUI.

How can I implement that GUI without coding anything? Any tool/solution comes up to your mind?

The easiest way I can imagine is saving those images locally on Ubuntu, and then having an HTML page generated every minute (by a scheduled script) and loaded into a Browser Tab with 1 minute auto-refresh, which reload that HTML page which includes all the images.

Any better GUI solution to implement a proper image stream that shows in my Ubuntu Desktop?

Regards,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution for displaying a stream of images in a GUI on Ubuntu without coding would be to use an image viewer application combined with a folder monitoring tool.
Here's a simple setup you can use:

1. Save Images Locally: As you suggested, save the images grabbed by your crawler locally on your Ubuntu machine.
2. Image Viewer: Use an image viewer application that can display images from a folder. Applications like feh or eog (Eye of GNOME).

3.Folder Monitoring: Utilize a folder monitoring tool like inotifywait or watchman to watch for changes in the folder where your images are being saved.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?